# SetMediaTime on a CSource filter makes output AVI nonsense - any idea why?

Tags: c++, video, directshow, avi

**Update: The code I originally posted did not actually reproduce the issue; my sincere apologies for not validating it. The key to the odd behavior is a small delta (300 UNITS = 30 microseconds) between when one frame ends and the next begins. For some reason the capture hardware I am using reports a different framerate than what it actually exhibits when it provides captured frames and their timestamps. I've updated the source below to give an example of how to imitate this behavior.**

I wrote a simple "fake" image source filter for directshow, deriving from CSource. It works well. But I've noticed something odd that I can't explain. My FillBuffer looks like:

```
const REFERENCE_TIME TIME_PER_FRAME = 166000;

HRESULT MyFilterOutputPin::FillBuffer(IMediaSample *pms)
{
    //fill the bytes of the image media sample
    static REFERENCE_TIME currentTime = 0;
    REFERENCE_TIME startTime = currentTime;
    REFERENCE_TIME endTime = currentTime + TIME_PER_FRAME; //60Hz video
    // The +300 below is an update not in the original question, and is the
    // key to reproducing the behavior.
    currentTime += TIME_PER_FRAME + 300;
    pms->SetTime(&startTime, &endTime);
    pms->SetMediaTime(&startTime, &endTime);
    return S_OK;
}
```

and my CMediaType is set by calling

```
SetCMediaTypeForBitmap(1920,1080,TIME_PER_FRAME,&cmt);
```

where that function is implemented as

```
void SetCMediaTypeForBitmap(unsigned long width, unsigned long height, REFERENCE_TIME averageTimePerFrame, CMediaType *pmt)
{
    CMediaType mt;
    mt.SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video);
    mt.SetSubtype(&MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24);
    mt.SetFormatType(&FORMAT_VideoInfo);
    mt.SetSampleSize(GetBitmapBufferSize(width, height, BIT_COUNT));
    auto pvi = (VIDEOINFOHEADER*)mt.AllocFormatBuffer(sizeof(VIDEOINFOHEADER));
    pvi->rcSource.left = pvi->rcSource.top = 0;
    pvi->rcSource.right = width;
    pvi->rcSource.bottom = height;
    pvi->rcTarget = pvi->rcSource;
    pvi->dwBitErrorRate = 0;
    pvi->AvgTimePerFrame = averageTimePerFrame;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biSize = 40;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = BIT_COUNT;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
    pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = mt.lSampleSize;
    pvi->dwBitRate = (DWORD)(((uint64_t)mt.lSampleSize) * 8 / pvi->AvgTimePerFrame * UNITS);
    pvi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = pvi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = pvi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = pvi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    *pmt = mt;
}
```

If I try to set the media time on my samples in my override of MyFilterOutputPin::FillBuffer and then write the output to an AVI file, the AVI file will, according to VirtualDub, have 300x the number of frames it should. It lists most frames as dropped and periodically has a real frame.

If I simply remove the SetMediaTime, the output AVI is completely normal.

I've experimented with different ways to set the media time. I can put times relative to the filter's m_pStart, times on the reference clock, etc. It doesn't seem to matter - just the presence of a MediaTime blows the AVI up.

I've seen proper directshow capture filters that set MediaTime just fine, so I'm guessing that I'm failing to do something. Any thoughts/ideas?

Here's a screenshot of my file properties for about 2 seconds of capture. 138 frames were truly output, but the AVI believes it has ~40000 frames, or 290 times the true number. If I run the same code without SetMediaTime, the AVI is 2 seconds long with 138 frames and. no "dropped" frames.
[image: Wonky AVI properties]

The non-dropped frames are at 0, 326, 552, 878, 1104, 1430, 1756, 1982. The deltas between those are 326, 226, 326, 226, 226, 326, 326, 226. It's definitely got me scratching my head...

Comment: An interesting observation looking at an existing capture filter that sets media times without any issue. There are **never** any gaps in the media times it sets, even though there may be gaps/overlap in the regular times set on the samples. So I think the big takeaway is that media times on consecutive samples cannot have gaps, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled onto [this bit of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/time-stamps) today and I think it actually explains things to some degree. From it,

> Optionally, the filter can also specify a media time for the sample.
> In a video stream, media time represents the frame number.

So the mux expects mediatimes, if present, like 0-1,1-2,2-3. When media times are set to contiguous chunks, like 0-100000,100000-200000, I'm guessing the mux copes. But when there are gaps, based on the documentation Microsoft provides, I can understand how things fall apart.

But knowing this is actually pretty powerful. Since AVI files are a constant framerate format, you can use mediatimes to communicate frame drops when you need them. I've started using them successfully for this purpose.

FYI, I tried including mediatimes based on actual times in a project again a few days ago and instead of funny results, the directshow graph would just stop with E_FAIL.

**tl;dr Only use media times to communicate frame numbers, at least to the AVI mux.**

Answer (score 1):

AVI frame index will have entries for every frame at fixed frame rate defined in the stream header. For example, you create 300 fps track and then your source time stamps samples with 1 fps frequency. The resulting file will have your frames and 299 dropped (zero length) frames between them. This is what you are supposedly getting.

That said your time stamping code snippet is about right (you do it in a straightforward way). However important also is what rate is applied to the stream itself, and this is derived from media type, which you did not include in the question and which you should inspect.

The match between media type rate and time stamps is the key to get accurate output AVI file.

Comment: Thanks for the input Roman. So I'm actually getting ~275 dropped non-zero length frames between the non-dropped frames. The number of dropped frames oddly switches between 225 and 325 (and never anything else). Everything is set up for a 60fps track, which is exactly what I get. With no SetMediaTime, outputting 60 frames gives me a 1 second clip. With SetMediaTime, it gives me approx. 276 second clip, with every real frame present, just a bunch of nonsense dropped frames in between.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the wacky AVI file properties and details about where the non-dropped frames are. It's quite peculiar.

Comment: Why don't you advance your current time counter by fixed increments equal to those in media type? As opposed 166000/166666 as in the code snippet. You still need to include the media type printout into the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding @Roman R. - was out on vacation. I cleaned up my code above to more accurately represent what I am doing - the frame duration is always the same, and is used to create the CMediaType appropriately - I've also included the code I use to set my CMediaType.

Comment: I think I skipped important part: "If I simply remove the `SetMediaTime`, the output AVI is completely normal.". `SetMediaTime` is optional and quite so often is simply not present. I guess it might be treated by AVI mux in some special way: ["filters are not required to set the media time"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407208). I'd remote media time just to fit the AVI mux as it responds to media time in this unpredictable way.

Comment: Thanks @Roman R. I just updated the question above after discovering my repro code did not actually repro the issue. My sincere and humble apologies. The reproduction seems to hinge on a small gap between sample timestamps. Why the gap only leads to issues when SetMediaTime is used is beyond me, but eliminating the gap makes the issue go away. Further, the CMediaType avgTimePerFrame doesn't seem to matter at all - basically a gap is the critical piece.

Comment: In one of the projects I still maintain the option to produce AVI files. I use there a special filter connected before AVI Mux, a filter that restamps data so that time stamps are exact multiples of frame numbers by `AvgTimePerFrame`. I assume that AVI mux does the reverse operation to get frame numbers back. Without such filter similar small fluctuations resulted in issues, but to my best knowledge there we breaking errors rather than nonsense output in resulting file.

Comment: Very interesting. Experimenting more, even a gap of 1 UNITS between media samples causes VirtualDub to report dropped frames. I think my lesson learned is that media times can't have gaps if you use them. Also, while VirtualDub will show the gapped file with dropped frames, the avi source filter in Graph Studio Next seems to not render the frames at all.

Comment: Really curious - would you recommend something besides an AVI to store raw uncompressed captures? I encode to mp4 eventually, but don't have time to do any compression during the capture.

Comment: It is not just AVI a pain, but DirectShow filters for AVI are not perfect either. With raw video the problem is AVI size limitation. Being skeptical that raw video captures are at all viable, my solution to raw captures is MP4. There is no time stamp problem there and there is no file size limit. The version of MP4 demultiplexer/multiplexer I maintain [here](https://github.com/roman380/gdcl.co.uk-mpeg4) offers support for [raw video media types](https://github.com/roman380/gdcl.co.uk-mpeg4/blob/master/mp4mux/TypeHandler.cpp#L521).

Comment: MP4 with raw video might be not suitable for playback in other systems/apps, but you can re-encode the content later as you like (mp4demux filter would read such MP4 files via DirectShow). Hardware accelerated video encoding is the better answer to this problem nowadays.